# Delete Timestamp in Image name by renaming in php

Tags: php, timestamp, rename, worker

quick question. If I need to rename files like this "file.d20140220-u162540.jpg", to "file.jpg" using the php rename function, what would the syntax be? I tried rename("*.d*", "*.jpg"); but that didn't work and I'm guessing that is as expected but I wanted to know what the correct syntax is. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substr_replace](https://www.php.net/substr_replace)

If only (in your case) everytime 17 characters long is, between `file` and `jpg`

[SEE DEMO](http://3v4l.org/CtUcK)

```
$stringToReplace = 'file.d20140220-u162540.jpg';
$string = substr_replace($stringToReplace, "", 4, 18);

echo $string;
```

Output: `file.jpg`

UPDATE:

So, all your files are `*.d20140220-u162540.jpg` then can you make like this way:

```
    $stringToReplace = "opening-ceremony-600x450.d20140220-u162540.jpg";

    // Get the length from file
    $removeTimestamp = strlen($stringToReplace); 

    // (d20140220-u162540.jpg === 21)
    $removeTimestamp = floor($removeTimestamp - 21);        
    $example_1 = substr_replace($stringToReplace, "jpg", $removeTimestamp);
    echo "Example 1: ".$example_1."\n\n";

    $stringToReplace = "marc-by-marc-jacobs-13-black-136831_3-90x90.d20140220-u071915.jpg";
    $removeTimestamp = strlen($stringToReplace);
    $removeTimestamp = floor($removeTimestamp - 21);
    $example_2 = substr_replace($stringToReplace, "jpg", $removeTimestamp);

    echo "Example 2: ".$example_2;
```

Output:

> Example 1: opening-ceremony-600x450.jpg
>
> Example 2: marc-by-marc-jacobs-13-black-136831_3-90x90.jpg

[SEE DEMO 2](http://3v4l.org/AlUXZ#v430)

Comment: Thanks!!! Would it make a difference if 'file.d20140220-u162540.jpg' is actually 'opening-ceremony-600x450.d20140220-u162540.jpg' for example? I have almost 1 million of these to go through and essentially the part labelled 'file' varies for each image, the .'d2014....-u.......jpg' also varies from file to file. An example showing 3 files I would like to change are:  "marc-by-marc-jacobs-13-black-t-shirt_136831_3-900x675.d20140220-u071914.jpg",
    "marc-by-marc-jacobs-13-black-136831_3-90x90.d20140220-u071915.jpg",
    "marc-by-marc-jacobs-13-black-94x70.d20140220-u071914.jpg"

Comment: Also, not all the files in the directory have '.d20140220-u071914.jpg' style names. Some are okay and have just the '.jpg' extension. This is why I was hoping to find a way to select those that have the timestamped extensions and amend the names (perhaps using a wildcard?).

Comment: Thanks!!! Much appreciated!  I should have been clearer, not all the files have this time stamp, some don't. How do I skip those ones that don't? I was thinking of maybe closing the code in an if statement perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I finally got this working by adding an if statement to filter out all the files affected and then renaming it using your code. The code is below:

$key is the filename

```
if (strpos($key, '.d201402') !== FALSE){
$stringToReplace = $key;
$removeTimestamp = strlen($stringToReplace);
$removeTimestamp = floor($removeTimestamp - 21);
$keytemp = substr_replace($stringToReplace, "jpg", $removeTimestamp);   
$grants = $s3->putObject(
array('Body'  => file_get_contents("https://your-bucket-name.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/".$key, 'r'), 
'Bucket'  => $args['bucket'],'Key' => $keytemp, 'ACL' => 'public-read','ContentType' =>     'image/jpeg'));  
echo 'Filename replaced - ';
echo $keytemp,"\n";

}
```